# 'Studies' or 'studies performed'

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I am wondering if "studies performed" and "studies" can be used interchangeably?

Such as:

1. I think that the studies performed, may be fundamental for ...
2. I think that the studies, may be fundamental for ...

Comment: I would drop the comma after studies in both cases. I do think you are correct that _performed_ is superfluous. Unless the context dictates you have to make it clear the studies have been performed and are not still in a planning phase, it looks like line-filling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context.

For instance, if you are talking about the scientific studies, it may take *performed*. See this -

> Many of the **studies performed** may be considered outdated - *performed* makes it better

As oerkelens said, dropping a comma makes it more natural.

On the other hand, simply putting *studies* also go but in this context or similar to this

> I think that the double-blind **studies** may be more reliable - removing *performed* is okay

Use *performed* when you want to *emphasize* on the completion of the task.

> [perform](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/perform?q=perform) - *Carry out, accomplish, or fulfill (an action, task, or function)*